# Vigorously remarket vs aggressively remarket

Tags: sentence-meaning

Which sentence is stronger and implies that the re-marketing agent is working his behind off to do the job?

Vigorously remarket the fleet.
Aggressively remarket the fleet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Aggressive` is the word.

It is also used in the marketing industry, like:

> Aggressive Marketing and Branding Strategies
>
> That was a very aggresive growth strategy

The word aggressive is generally used when the work is being done with all the efforts possible, by the team. (like `firing on all cylinders`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either works. Look up the definition of [vigorous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vigorous) or [aggressive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aggressive?s=t)

Why can't you just say "the re-marketeer is doing his utmost best to ...", or something like that?